# Definition of independence doesn't tell $how$ dependent random variables are, $if$ they are dependent

Tags: probability, random-variables

**(In the following I'm only talking about discrete space, variables etc.)**

The definition of independence is such that when two events are *dependent* we don't exactly know, how the dependence is.

Let me specify this: Suppose we have two *dependent* random variables $X,Y$ on or space $\Omega$; that means, that there exists $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that the events $X^{-1}(A)\subseteq\Omega$ and $Y^{-1}(B)\subseteq\Omega$ are dependent. But how does this translate to what we can say about the distribution of, say, $Y$, if we know the distribution of $X$ ? What is the connection between their distributions ?

I'm asking this since [here](http://www.statlect.com/inddst1.htm), right at the beginning, it says that "two random variables are independent if they convey no information about each other and, as a consequence, receiving information about one of the two does not change our assessment of the probability distribution of the other", so if the variables are dependent there would have to be a connection between their distributions.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem

Comment: @Learner Yes $    $

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Well I thought a little bit about it, but that doesn't yet give me what I want for random variables...I found this (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability#Calculation) which seems to be what you are insinuating, but that is rather complicated...

Comment: "...that means, that for every..." should rather be "... that means that for some..."

Comment: @leonbloy  I think"for some" is not a mathematical term. "For every" should be ok, see for instance http://www.statlect.com/inddst1.htm

Comment: But it's false that the "dependence" must hold for every subset pair. The _independence_ propery must hold for _every_ subset pair; if it does not hold for _some_ $A,B$, then they are dependent.

Comment: ah, yes sorry, I forgot I talked about dependence rather than independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional probability tells how a variable depends (pointwise) on another one. Assuming discrete distributions:
$$P(Y=y | X=x) = \frac{P(X=x \cap Y=y)}{P(X=x)}$$

If they are indendependent

$$P(Y=y | X=x) = \frac{P(X=x) P(Y=y)}{P(X=x)}=P(Y=y)$$

Elsewhere, if they are not independent, knowing the value of $X$ changes the distribution of $Y$ (at least for some values of $X$ and $Y$).

> what we can say about the distribution of, say, $Y$, if we know the
>   distribution of $X$

Nothing. If we know the *value* of $X$ , and assuming that we know the full joint distribution of $X,Y$ we can know the conditioned distribution of $Y$, $P(Y|X)$.

Comment: I pondered a while on your answer but could not quite follow you on the last sentence. Could you please tell me/sketch a proof why "If we know the value of X , and assuming that we know the full joint distribution of X,Y we can know the conditioned distrubution of Y, P(Y|X)." holds ?

Comment: @user26698 : It's just the first equation (I rewrote it with the letter swapped, so that it fits better the statement).